# Unable to find a constructor to use for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Client.HttpConnection

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, signalr.client

I am trying to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` in a `Xamarin Forms` project.
My android application works fine in Debug Version.
But it doesn't work in the Release version

`(Android Options => Linking = "Sdk and User Assemblies" )`.

Exception :

> Invalid negotiation response received. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Client.HttpConnection+NegotiationResponse. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'connectionId', line 1, position 16.

Answer (score 0):

> A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.

You could refer to the following link, they have the exact same problem with you :

- [JsonSerializationException in release mode](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16453/jsonserializationexception-in-release-mode)
- [Deserialization not working with JSON.NET](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15152/deserialization-not-working-with-json-net-on-ios-device-ios-simulator-works)

As T.J.Purtell.1752 said :

> you need to annotate classes that are accessed via reflection only (aka things deserialized via JSON.NET) with a flag to tell the compiler to never strip them.

And as they suggested, try using `[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]` in your project.

## Update :

> the slider Value is changing?

Modify your `MainPage.xaml` like this :

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"
       Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='{0:F0}'}"
       FontSize="96" />

<SliderMinimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding SlideValue, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="slider"/>
```

Then the `Label` can display the `Silder` value.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Client.HttpConnection.cs is a signalR package class.
I can't add [Preserve(AllMembers = true)] annotation

Comment: @MohamedBenSaid, where did you add this annotation? Could you please post your code?

Comment: i am using this example : https://github.com/rizamarhaban/XamarinSignalRCore/tree/master/MobileClient

Comment: @MohamedBenSaid, I test this sample in release mode, but failed to reproduce your problem, are you using the exact same code as this sample?

Comment: yes but i just added a try catch in this class.
https://github.com/rizamarhaban/XamarinSignalRCore/blob/master/MobileClient/MobileClient/MobileClient/Services/SignalRClient.cs

public async Task InitializeSignalR()
{
HubConnection _hub;
try
{
_hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl(url)
.Build();
await _hub.StartAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception :{0}", ex));
}
}

Comment: @MohamedBenSaid, Would you mind sharing your project, to make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using?

Comment: I have not added SignalR yet to my project. I test the example for integret after in my project.

Comment: This example work fine in debug mode when ( Linking = "None") in Android Options.

Comment: But when i change (Linking = "Sdk and User Assemblies"), i get a exception (not crash).

Comment: To display it in console, i added try catch block :
        public async Task InitializeSignalR()
        {
            try
            {
                _hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://192.168.1.8:8088/updater")
                .Build();                
                await _hub.StartAsync();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception :{0}", ex));              
            }            
        }

Comment: @MohamedBenSaid, sorry, I use `None` and `Sdk and User Assemblies Only`, none of them can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: the slider Value is changing?

Comment: so you can find the problem ?

Comment: @MohamedBenSaid, I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: I think, you didn't understand my problem.
thank you.